# Tum toe tap drain removal

Tags: plumbing, drain, bathtub

I am trying to clear a clog in my bath drain with toe touch stop. I have removed the top portion by unscrewing it. I can’t turn the screw in the bottom portion at all. How can I get it out?  Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You’ll need a tub drain extractor. Menards, Lowe’s, Home Depot will have it.

Comment: Please make this answer more useful by adding information about the tool that you propose and possibly a photo of the tool. Describe how this tool can be used specifically to remove the component that the OP has asked about.